# DateDiff In months between two different types date formats

Tags: sql, type-conversion, datediff

I have two date formats, EndDate in `YYYYMMDD` format and another Monthfirstdate in `YYYY-MM-DD` FORMAT. I need to get the difference between these two dates.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @Date DATE = dbo.value('DATE')


SELECT 
     E.EmployeeID
    ,E.StartDateKey
    ,E.EndDateKey
    ,E.FromDateKey
    ,E.ToDateKey

INTO #Employee

FROM
    dbo.Employee E

---clean--

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, 0, @Date) - 1, 0))
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @Date) + 3, 0)) 
        
SELECT
    E.EmployeeID

    ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), E.StartDateKey, 112) AS INT) AS _EmployeeStartDateKey
    ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), E.EndDateKey, 112) AS INT)   AS _EmployeeFinishDateKey
    ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, D.MonthFirstDay, 112) AS INT)    AS _DateKey
    ,????                           AS [Tenure]
    
FROM #Employee AS E
        
INNER JOIN dbo.Date D ON 
    D.DateKey BETWEEN E.FromDateKey AND E.ToDateKey 

WHERE 
    D.DateKey BETWEEN @tartDate AND @EndDate
    AND D.DayOfMonth = 1
```

Comment: Which Database you are using?

Comment: Relational database and I would like to convert Monthfirstdate to YYYYMMDD so it matches with EndDate.

Comment: You want to calculate date difference in month, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: You should never store dates as string, which I assume you're doing because you're talking about the format (dates in databases do not have a format).

Comment: Yes, James, noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query in **SQL Server**:

```
DECLARE 
    @firstDate DATETIME = '2022-12-01',
    @dateinStringFormat VARCHAR(20)= '20121201',
    @endDate DATETIME;

    --Converting date string to Datetime format(YYYY-MM-DD)
    SELECT @endDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, @dateinStringFormat), 120);

    --Now, Calculating the date difference in Month
    SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @endDate, @firstDate) AS DateDiff;
```

Comment: I have to insert it into the running script, I will provide the query for clarity.

Comment: You mean in the select query portion? Please share your query

Comment: I have updated the query, in the question box, need to calculate Tenure which is the difference in months between the start date and the month's first date.